# Cant iterate over vec<&str> and pass element into option_env!()?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, toml

Sorry if this is a noob question.

I've created a .cargo/config.toml file in my project and configured some env variables like so:

```
[env]
GAME_ZERO_LEVEL = "0"
GAME_ZERO_MULTIPLIER = "0.1"
GAME_ONE_LEVEL = "1"
GAME_ONE_MULTIPLIER = "1.0"
GAME_TWO_LEVEL = "2"
GAME_TWO_MULTIPLIER = "2.5"
GAME_THREE_LEVEL = "3"
GAME_THREE_MULTIPLIER = "5.0"
GAME_FOUR_LEVEL = "4"
GAME_FOUR_MULTIPLIER = "10.0"
```

I will parse these into u32 and f32.

Anyway, I'm able to fetch these individually with

```
let value = option_env!("GAME_ZERO_LEVEL").unwrap();
```

Here is the problem, I want to fetch all env variables in a loop like so:

```
let env_keys: Vec<&str> = vec![
    "GAME_ZERO_LEVEL",
    "GAME_ZERO_MULTIPLIER",
    "GAME_ONE_LEVEL",
    "GAME_ONE_MULTIPLIER",
    "GAME_TWO_LEVEL",
    "GAME_TWO_MULTIPLIER",
    "GAME_THREE_LEVEL",
    "GAME_THREE_MULTIPLIER",
    "GAME_FOUR_LEVEL",
    "GAME_FOUR_MULTIPLIER",
];

env_keys.iter().for_each(|key| {
    let value = option_env!(key).unwrap();        //error here
    // do some stuff with it
}
```

But I get the following compile error
`rustc: argument must be a string literal`

Safe to say, Im pretty confused as my previous understanding was that `&str` are string literals, and that passing in a `&str` in a variable doesnt't work. Any help understanding this would be much appreciated!

Note: I cant use std::env::{var, vars}

Comment: What you might need is [`dotenv`](https://docs.rs/dotenv/latest/dotenv/) which works outside of the `cargo` environment.

Comment: If you need to read the environment variables at compile-time, this can be achieved with a macro: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e4d408b85b98fe5cd320b98670ee160b).

Comment: This worked amazingly, thank you/q

Answer (score 0):

Slight misconception there `&str` or more specifically `&'static str`is the type of string literals but string literals are just the ones you type literally like this: `"this is a string literal"`, or this `r"I'm a raw string literal"` or even like this `r#"I'm a raw string literal which can contain " wherever"#`. Everything else is not a literal. Things that are not string literals also can have that type though.

Compare also [string literals in Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/str.html#literals-and-escapes) and [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#string-literals)

`option_env!()` evaluates it's contents at compile time so you can't use it with runtime variables like your `key`.